# SQL to select row in target table based on data in multiple rows in driver table

Tags: sql-server

All,

Please see below data values in two tables:

FIRST Table: or Driver table contains Filter Criteria for selecting IDs from second Table

```
Key1    Value
1    Banks
1    Col1|Small
2    InsuranceCompany
2    Col2|Global
3    Banks
3    Col1|Big
3    Col2|Local
4    CreditUnion
```

Script

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_DRIVER](
    [Key1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
    );
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('1', 'Banks');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('1', 'Col1|Small');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('2', 'InsuranceCompany');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('2', 'Col2|Global');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('3', 'Banks');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('3', 'Col1|Big');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('3', 'Col2|Local');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST_DRIVER(Key1, Value)
VALUES('4', 'CreditUnion');
GO
```

Note: 
a) Filter Criteria may exist in 1, 2 or 3 rows.
b) First selection criteria will always join with InstitutionType column of second table, however second and third criteria may or may not exist and the column to which it will join is specified in data itself with | separating columns name with value

SECOND Table: IDs from this table need to be found based on filter criteria in FIRST Table

```
ID  InstitutionType     Col1        Col2
100 Banks               Small   
200 Banks                           Global
300 Banks               Big         Local
400 InsuranceCompany    Small       Local
500 InsuranceCompany                Global
600 CreditUnion         Small       Local
700 CreditUnion                     Global
800 CDO                             Global
```

Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InstitutionType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Col2] [varchar](50) NULL
    );
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('100',  'Banks', 'Small', '');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('200',  'Banks', '', 'Global');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('300',  'Banks', 'Big', 'Local');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('400',  'InsuranceCompany', 'Small', 'Local');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('500',  'InsuranceCompany', '', 'Global');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('600',  'CreditUnion', 'Small', 'Local');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('700',  'CreditUnion', '', 'Global');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST_TARGET](ID, InstitutionType, Col1, Col2)
VALUES('800',  'CDO', '', 'Global');
GO
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
ID
100
300
500
600
700
```

I am able to do it using cursor/while loop however I want to do it using query logic. Can someone please try to answer this interesting problem?

Comment: Don't you mean SELECT logic not SET logic?

Comment: You wouldn't end up with so called interesting problem if you would design your tables properly...

Comment: Hi James, I agree with your point however there are times when your hands are tied when you need to source data from external systems and push data into external systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will work and produce the exact results as your sample output, but seems a bit off how you are matching the records.  Looks like you are only matching on Value and ignoring col1 & col2 in the driver table if they are both not available (which is why you are selecting 600 & 700) but not if one or the other exist?  I would expect that once the driver table is transformed with col1 and col2 in the proper format, you would want to just join to it on all the columns like this:

`on t.InstitutionType = d.Value`
`and coalesce(t.col1,'') = coalesce(d.col1,'')`
`and coalesce(t.col2,'') = coalesce(d.col2,'')`

If there happened to be a mistake in your sample output, you can update the join condition in the code below.

```
with test_driver_cte AS 
(select 
Key1,
max(case when Value not like '%|%' then Value end) Value,
max(case when Value like '%|%' and col = 'Col1' then value2 end) Col1,
max(case when Value like '%|%' and col = 'Col2' then value2 end) Col2
from (
    select 
        key1,
        Value,
        case when value like '%|%'
             then substring(Value, 1, 4)
        end col,
        case when value like '%|%'
             then substring(Value, 6, 10)  --change 2nd parameter to length of Value-6
        end value2                   
    from test_driver
    ) td
group by key1
)

select distinct ID 
from test_target t
join test_driver_cte d
on (t.InstitutionType = d.Value and d.col1 is null and d.col2 is null)
or (t.InstitutionType = d.Value and t.col1 = d.col1)
or (t.InstitutionType = d.Value and t.col2 = d.col2)
```

Comment: take a look at how I used COALESCE in my answer -- this is the same join with less logic (and thus faster.)

Comment: @Hogan only problem I saw with that was if col1 or col2 happen to be null on table2 also you wouldn't get a match.

Comment: Oh I see you mean the version with all 3 fields concatenated together.  That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a table like this

```
Key1 Value            Col1   Col2
1    Banks            Small
2    InsuranceCompany        Global
3    Banks            Big    Local
4    CreditUnion
```

If you can't make it start that way then you can transform it like this:

```
SELECT D.Key1, D.Value, SUBSTRING(C1.Value,6) AS Col1, SUBSTRING(C2.Value,6) AS Col2
FROM DRIVER D
JOIN DRIVER c1 on D.Key1 = c1.Key1 AND LEFT(c1.Value,5) = 'Col1|'
JOIN DRIVER c2 on D.Key1 = c2.Key1 AND LEFT(c2.Value,5) = 'Col2|'
WHERE LEFT(D.Value,3) != 'Col'
```

Now you just join to get your result:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE2
JOIN (
  SELECT D.Key1, D.Value, SUBSTRING(C1.Value,6) AS Col1, SUBSTRING(C2.Value,6) AS Col2
  FROM DRIVER D
  JOIN DRIVER c1 on D.Key1 = c1.Key1 AND LEFT(c1.Value,5) = 'Col1|'
  JOIN DRIVER c2 on D.Key1 = c2.Key1 AND LEFT(c2.Value,5) = 'Col2|'
  WHERE LEFT(D.Value,3) != 'Col'
) x ON TABLE2.InstitutionType = x.Key1 
     AND COALESCE(x.col1,TABLE2.Col1) = TABLE2.Col1
     AND COALESCE(x.col2,TABLE2.Col2) = TABLE2.Col2
```

You could also do the join like this (which might be more or less clear, but is the same)

```
) x ON (x.Key1, COALESCE(x.col1,TABLE2.Col1), COALESCE(x.col2,TABLE2.Col2)) = 
       (TABLE2.InstitutionType, TABLE2.Col1, TABLE2.Col2)
```

I did not test so I might have a typo or an off by one on the substring.

Comment: Hi Hogan, Thanks for your suggestion.
However, I am receiving first table from UI, and have no control over their structure. The second table is again an existing DW Table and cannot be modified. I can only derive data based on these two tables, not change structure of either of them.

Comment: @Nilesh you say suggestion, I say solution.